# Why isn't the navbar showing correctly in Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I encountered this error while trying to create a navbar with Bootstrap,
the result should be a navbar but it's not, trying to understand the nature of the error I copied W3schools's code( https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_navbar.asp )in the editor (Atom). Both my code and W3schools's code aren't working, but they seems to be correctly written. Where am I wrong? May I have your help please?

This is my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">


  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-alpBpkh1PFOepccYVYDB4do5UnbKysX5WZXm3XxPqe5iKTfUKjNkCk9SaVuEZflJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <body>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <nav class=“navbar”>

      <nav class="navbar">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href=“#”>Something</a>
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
          <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">One</li>
    </ul>
</nav>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: W3School's code is fine: https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_navbar&stacked=h. Also, jquery library should be declared before the bootstrap one since it depends on it.

Comment: The code in the W3School link is for Bootstrap 3.x and in your code you are loading Bootstrap 4.x, both are very different, I don't think the code from W3Schools will work with Bootstrap 4.

Answer (score 0):

Before including bootstrap, you should include jquery...
For example:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your Text Formatted Quotes from this.

```
 <nav class=“navbar”>
```

To Non text Formatted quotes.

```
 <nav class="navbar">
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code you are using Bootstrap 4.x, which is the newest release and is completely different, many things look quite similar between 3.x and 4.x but in short anything that worked in 3.x has more chances to break in 4.x.

So instead of using W3School's code as your reference, use Twitter Bootstrap's documentation for version 4.0 :
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/

Also, your HTML code doesn't look quite right, for e.g this line

`<li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">One</li>`

You forgot to close `<a>`. So it is important you take a look at your code and see if something is being caused by a syntax error. Other than that if fix the code the output is what you will get from the HTML. Nothing sort of a navbar because you have to follow Twitter Bootstrap 4's guideline on lay-outing a navbar

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/

Another issue is that you have put `boostrap.min.js` before `jQuery`, for Bootstrap's JavaScript to work you first have to load jQuery.

Good luck.